# Rename ticks from y-axis in seaborn.barplot

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I have the following dataframe, called 'df_top_movies' :

[image: df_top_movies]

And later I display this data in a seaborn.barplot:

```
sns.barplot(x="revenue", y="title", data=df_top_movies).set(ylabel='movie')
```

[image: barplot]

Is it posible to show in y-axis the title of the movie with release_year?

Example:

- Jaws (1975)
- The Exorcist (1973)

Previously, I've created a list with the movies and the year:

```
target_names = list(df_top_movies.apply(lambda movie : movie['title'] + " ("+ str(movie['release_year']) + ")", axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="revenue", y="title", data=df_top_movies)
ax.set_yticklabels(target_names)
```

The function `sns.barplot` returns a matplotlib object of the type `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. These objects offer multiple methods to customise ticks and axes. It's a common pattern to generate a seaborn plot and then tweak it by calling the `ax` set methods.

You can see the documentation of set_yticklabels [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html). You'll see that the method accepts other arguments to change, for example, the fontsize and orientation of the labels.